# VIM - NerdTree - Open Bookmarks when VIM is started

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I set VIM to open NERDTree whenever VIM is started by doing this: autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree

What changes should I make to my vimrc file so that the Bookmarks also open up whenever VIM & NerdTree are started?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`let NERDTreeShowBookmarks=1` will display the bookmarks table on startup.  If you wanted to actually open the files for editing, I'm not sure how to do that.

NERDTree provides a very nice documentation file.  If you extracted the zip file in ~/.vim, it is located at ~/.vim/doc/NERD_tree.txt.  If you want to use with vim's built in help, run `:helptags ~/.vim/doc/` and then you'll be able to access it with `:help NERDTree`.

Of course, if you extracted the zip someplace else, replace ~/.vim with the folder you extracted it into.

Comment: cool, I didn't know how to load that help file, it's Very useful.  So to open NERDTree straight to a bookmark, just do `autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree bookmarkName`

Comment: `:help NERDTree` on vim

Answer (score 7):

From the help file of Nerdtree :

> 2.2.1. The Bookmark Table *NERDTreeBookmarkTable*
>   If the bookmark table is active (see |NERDTree-B| and |'NERDTreeShowBookmarks'|), it will be rendered above the tree. You can double click bookmarks or use the |NERDTree-o| mapping to activate them. See also, |NERDTree-t| and |NERDTree-T|

So I guess that
`let NERDTreeShowBookmarks=1` in your `.vimrc` should work.

Answer (score 4):

I know this question was asked a while ago but since it is at the top of the google results I thought I would give the proper answer.

In your .vimrc file NERDTreeFromBookmark will not op a bookmark name BUT it will open a hard path.

For example:

```
au VimEnter *  NERDTreeFromBookmark /path/to/your/bookmark/folder/
```

This will open NERDTree at that location on VIM startup.

Hope that helps some people.

**EDIT:**

im guessing you could also do:

```
au VimEnter *  NERDTree /path/to/a/folder/
```

Comment: This is actually the answer I was looking for. Thank you.